# Contact form working partially

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

i need some help with this contact form im trying to fix.
The thing is that it works... kinda. i do get the messages but no success confirmation. the form just fades out a lil' bit and get's stuck i guess but the message does go through.
Any ideas of what im missing here?

```
<form action="#" id="contact-form">
    <div class="input-group name-email">
        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Naam/Bedrijf" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Telefoon" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Bericht" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="submit" id="form-submit" class="pull-right" value="Verzenden      ">
    </div>
</form>
```

that is my form script

```
    $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },

        message: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "name",
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: "no email"
        },
        message: {
            required: "no msg",
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            type: "POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            url: "process.php",
            success: function() {
                $('#contact-form :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#contact-form').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).find('label').css('cursor', 'default');
                    $('#success').fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#contact-form').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $('#error').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    });
    }); 
</script>
```

validation

```
<?php

$to = "";
$from = $_REQUEST['name'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$headers = "From: $from";

$fields = array();
$fields{"name"} = "name";
$fields{"email"} = "email";
$fields{"subject"} = "subject";
$fields{"message"} = "message";

$body = "Here is what was sent:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);?>
```

and finally my process.php script. any help would be appreciated. thanks.

```
<div id="success">
<span>
<p>Your message was sent successfully! I will be in touch as soon as I can.</p>
</span>
</div>

<div id="error">
<span>
<p>Something went wrong, try refreshing and submitting the form again.</p>
</span>
</div>
```

I have this piece of code as well at the end in the HTML but it just prints with or without submitting

Comment: I don't see `#success` in the HTML your provided. How is that defined?

Comment: yes i forgot to copy the whole thing. i've posted it just now

Comment: so you just need an echo if the message sent??